# Java Threads with Boss-Worker

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, blockingqueue

I have to do schoolwork, and I have some code done, but got some questions:

**must create a boss-workers application in java.**

1. I have these classes: `Main WorkerThread BossThread Job`

Basically what I want to do is, that `BossThread` holds a `BlockingQueue` and workers go there and look for `Jobs`.

**Question 1:**

At the moment I start 5 `WorkingThreads` and 1 `BossThread`.

Main:

```
Collection<WorkerThread> workers = new ArrayList<WorkerThread>();
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread();
        workers.add(worker);
    }
BossThread thread = new BossThread(jobs, workers);
thread.run();
```

BossThread:

```
private BlockingQueue<Job> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Job>(100);
private Collection<WorkerThread> workers;

public BossThread(Set<Job> jobs, Collection<WorkerThread> workers) {
    for(Job job : jobs) {
        queue.add(job);
    }
    for(WorkerThread worker : workers) {
        worker.setQueue(queue);
    }
    this.workers = workers;
}
```

Is this normal, or I should create `WorkerThreads` in my `BossThread` ?

**Question 2:**

As you see I am giving the queue to each `WorkerThread` , is that reasonable or I could store the queue only in one place?

**Question 3:**

Must I keep my `BossThread` running somehow, just to wait if user adds more stuff to queue? And how I keep `WorkerThreads` running, to look for jobs from queue?

**Any overall suggestions or design flaws or suggestions?**

```
public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Job> queue;

    public WorkerThread() {

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            queue.take().start();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setQueue(BlockingQueue<Job> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use an `ExecutorService` it combines a Queue with a Thread Pool and would replace much of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, one important mistake I noticed:

```
BossThread thread = new BossThread(jobs, workers));
thread.run();
```

`Runnable`s must be passed to a `Thread` object and threads are started with `start`, not `run`. By calling `run` you get sequential execution on the same thread. So:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new BossThread(jobs, workers)));
thread.start();
```

Secondly, unless you absolutely must use `BlockingQueue` and explicit threads I would instead use `ExecutorService`. It neatly encapsulates a blocking work queue and a team of workers (whose size you can set). It's basically what you're doing but much simpler to use:

```
class Job implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // work
    }
}

...

// create thread pool with 5 threads and blocking queue
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

// submit some work
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   exec.submit(new Job());
}
```

And that's it! All the `put` and `take` stuff is handled by the executor automatically.

Comment: But my BossThread implements Runnable, when I change run to start, then I get : `The method start() is undefined for the type BossThread`

Comment: @Jaanus: See my edit at the beginning. It means you are not starting the thread correctly. You need to pass the `Runnable` to a `Thread` object.

Comment: Must my Job implement Runnable? At the moment it is just class, that does work with method `doWork()`, and only things that implement runnable are bossthread, workerthread. Furtheremore it seems that Workerthreads will each have individual queues like this, not shared queue with boss.

Comment: @Jaanus: It must implement `Runnable` if you use `ExecutorService`. The `submit` method expects a `Runnable`. There is only one shared queue with `ExecutorService`, like in your case.

Comment: But since it is my schoolwork, I think I must implement some things myself, not use the service. So in my example, it seems like I will have a queue per Worker, but I need them to use only 1 queue.

Comment: @Jaanus: You are passing the same queue to all the workers so they all use the same queue.